# Using a custom shortcode from within the template of a shortcode plugin

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode

I've written a custom plugin, `ta-intentclicks` which is used as a shortcode:

```
[ta-intentclicks count="3" category="SEC-EDR"...]
```

Within this shortcode I'd like to use another shortcode that I can use as a helper. For example; in one of the PHP templates within my plugin.

```
[ta-intentclicks-link url="$list_item['link']"]Visit website[/ta-intentclicks-link]
[ta-intentclicks-link url="$list_item['link']"]<img src="foo" />[/ta-intentclicks-link]
```

Which would output this:

```
<a href="<the URL>" rel="sponsored" target="_blank" class="icp-list-link">Visit website</a>
<a href="<the URL>" rel="sponsored" target="_blank" class="icp-list-link"><img src="foo" /></a>
```

Here's a quick directory snapshot to help illustrate my question.
[image]

The plugin entry point is `includes/class-ta-intentclicks.php` which defines the shortcode and runs it, calling the Layout class along the way.

```
class TaIntentClicks {

    function __construct() {
        add_shortcode('ta-intentclicks', array($this, 'run'));
    }

    function run($attributes = []) {
        ... do some stuff
        return $this->layout->render($response, $layoutAttributes, $dataAttributes);
    }

}

class TAIntentClicksLayout {
    function parse($stuff, $template) {

        ob_start();
        $output = '';
        include $template;
        $output = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $output;
    }

    function render($response, $layoutAttributes, $dataAttributes) {

        return $this->parse(
            $response,
            $layoutAttributes,
            $this->getTemplate($layoutAttributes),
            $dataAttributes
        );
    }
}
```

I've seen examples of people calling "do_shortcode" to execute a shortcode, but I'm unclear where the shortcode function goes in my case, OR where to place the "do_shortcode" call.

Can anyone offer guidance here? This is my first plugin and I'm a bit lost as to how and implement this functionality. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, inside the *shortcode template*, you could do something like this:

```php
echo do_shortcode( '[ta-intentclicks-link url="' . esc_url( $list_item['link'] ) . '"]Visit website[/ta-intentclicks-link]' );
```

But then, **instead of having to use [`do_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/)**, you could actually simply call the shortcode callback from the (shortcode) template ( which then eliminates the need to find and parse shortcodes in the content or the first parameter for `do_shortcode()` ):

- If you registered the shortcode like so:

  ```php
  add_shortcode( 'ta-intentclicks-link', 'my_shortcode' );
  function my_shortcode( $atts = array(), $content = null ) {
      $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
          'url' => '',
      ), $atts );

      if ( ! empty( $atts['url'] ) ) {
          return sprintf( '<a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a>',
              esc_url( $atts['url'] ), esc_html( $content ? $content : $atts['url'] ) );
      }

      return '';
  }
  ```
- Then in the shortcode template, you could simply call the `my_shortcode()` function above:

  ```php
  echo my_shortcode( array(
      'url' => $list_item['link'],
  ), 'Visit website' );
  ```

But if that's not what you meant, or if you had a shortcode in a shortcode like `[caption]Caption: [myshortcode][/caption]`, then as said in the [Shortcode API on the WordPress Codex website](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Enclosing_vs_self-closing_shortcodes):

> If the enclosing shortcode is intended to permit other shortcodes in
> its output, the handler function can call
> [`do_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/)
> recursively:
>
> ```
> function caption_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
>   return '<span class="caption">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</span>';
> }
> ```

... your `run()` function (or the shortcode callback) would need to capture the second parameter passed to the function, i.e. `$content` as you could see above, and once you have that parameter (or its value), you can then call `do_shortcode()`.

(With the above "caption" shortcode example, the `$content` is the `Caption: [myshortcode]`.)

So for example, your `run()` function be written like so…

```php
// 1. Define the $content variable.
function run( $attributes = [], $content = null ) {
    // ... your code (define $response, $layoutAttributes, $dataAttributes, etc.)

    // 2. Then do something like so:
    return $this->layout->render( $response, $layoutAttributes, $dataAttributes ) .
        do_shortcode( $content );
}
```

But if you need further help with that, do let me know in the comments (and preferably, please show the code in your template and explain the variables like the `$response` and `$layoutAttributes`).

Answer (score 1):

```
function parse($stuff, $template) {
    ob_start();
    $output = '';
    include $template;
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $output = do_shortcode($output); // This line will parse shortcodes from $template
    return $output;
}
```

To add some details: your main shortcode, `[ta-intentclicks]`, I assume you're placing that in the Page/Post content. WordPress runs `do_shortcode` on `the_content` so that works as expected.

`do_shortcode` does not recursively run shortcodes, meaning, nested shortcodes just display as plain text wrapped in brackets / they do not render the shortcode content. So, you need to run `do_shortcode` again on the content of your shortcode to process the next "level" of the shortcode. Likewise, if you have a shortcode inside of that shortcode inside of `[ta-intentclick`], you'd need to run `do_shortcode` a second time (third time if you count WP's core running of it).

I'm not sure that this behavior is specifically documented, but if you read through the [do_shortcode source code here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.7.1/src/wp-includes/shortcodes.php#L196) it's apparent it doesn't handle sub-shortcodes.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use this simple code to do that?
I mean, it doesn't require shortcode inside shortcode.

```
function links( $atts, $content = null ){
    $args = shortcode_atts( array(
        's' => '', //name
        'l' => '', //link
    ), $atts);

    return '<a href="'. $args['l'] .'">'. $args['s'] .'</a>';
}
add_shortcode ('link', 'links');
```

you can write `[link s="NAME" l="LINK"]`
and it is more simple.

Comment: The main reason is that I need to conditionalize the inclusion of the link. So for a given piece of text, one of my admins can include a property that says "this should be a link, or this should not be a link". Also, it's easy to link a string of text, but harder to wrap a link around a dynamic image tag.